# How can I do this similar public static declarations to Java in Python?

Tags: java, python

In my Java I have a central boot loader which keeps on boot all default values as public static or private static, and later when require I can go to other class/threads and access them to do modify etc. For example:

```
public class main extends JWindow implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

  private static boolean isDetect = true;
  public  static String  vncMode  = "1980";
  ...

  public main() { 
    vncMode = C.readIni("vncmode"); // 1980
  }    
}

public class TCPHandler implements Runnable {
  import main.*;
  public void run() {
    if (main.vncMode.equals("1999" ) || 
        main.vncMode.equals("2013")) {
      echo(main.vncMode, RED);
    } else {
      echo(main.vncMode, GREEN);
    }
  }
}
```

Similar to Java, in Python, How can i set public static/private static declarations, so that i can have access from any other class of that value?

python1.py:

```
from bgcolors import bgcolors
class Python1(object):
  isDetect = True  
  def run(self):
    # expecting vncMode = 1980
    print bgcolors.RED +  "we are now in 1999: from version: " + vncMode
```

python2.py:

```
from bgcolors import bgcolors
class Python2(object):
  isDetect = True  
  def run(self):
    # expecting vncMode = 1980
    print bgcolors.RED + "we are now in 2013: from version: " + vncMode
```

main.py:

```
from bgcolors import bgcolors
from python1 import Python1
from python2 import Python2

vncMode = "1980"

a = Python1()
a.run()

b = Python2()
b.run()
```

How can i set the value 1980 and in all class get 1980 ?

Comment: It's easier to achieve what you're trying to do in Python if you forget how Java does it. Why do you need to do it this way? What are Python1 and Python2?

Comment: May I humbly suggest that you read this before: [Java dev learning Python: what concepts do I need to wrap my head around?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/47370/11732). In short, everything is public in Python, unless it's a class member named with two underscores in the front.

Comment: @Blender: Python1 and Python2 is encoder and decoder for video/audio codec which runs using Gtk both has TCP handlers and some TCP stacks, who will need to share packets between Python1 to Python2 and keep a snapshot in main.py for later use.

Comment: @YumYumYum: So why don't you just pass `vncMode` into `Python1.__init__`? `a = Python1(mode=1980)`?

Comment: @Blender: That i have done. But now i need also Python1 sends copy of move=1980 back to main.py so that Python2, 3... all others can share the updated stack. Else ihave to use modfifo.

Comment: Python1 : receives 1980 and it generate new stack (encoder/decoder), then it returns a copy of new stack to main.py, for all other classes. to use the update version. How do you return? from Python1 the same mode variable values?

Comment: @YumYumYum: Then write some sort of "manager" class that handles communication between the instances of your classes. This'd be much easier to answer if you included all of the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a container that stores the attributes you want to share

```
# example, could be a simple tuple, a full class or instance or dictionary, etc.
attributes = namedtuple("attributes", "vncmode")("1980")
```

you can pass the attributes to all of the classes on initialisation:

```
class ...:
    def __init__(self, attributes, ...):
        self.attributes = attributes
```

and then the instances can use `self.attributes.vncmode` as a shared mutable value.

Answer (score 0):

While I would normally use an argument to `__init__`, and explicitly pass the value to each instance upon creation, python has the `global` keyword to do something along the lines of what you are asking.

```
a_name = "A Value"

class Sample(object):
    def a_method(self):
        global a_name
        print a_name

sample_instance = Sample()
sample_instance.a_method()  # prints "A Value"
```

but you really should do something like...

```
a_name = "A Value"

class Sample2(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def a_method(self):
        print self.value

sample_instance = Sample2(a_name)
sample_instance.a_method()  # prints "A Value"
```